# Store a chess move in one byte at average case

Tags: algorithm, byte, storage, chess

I want an efficient, one byte way to store a chess move. Standard Algebraic chess notation takes too many bytes, and other solutions I came up with (such as numbering the squares 0-63 and them appending the numbers one after the other) also don't work. I also understand that stuff like promoting might take more than one byte, but I want a standard move to take an average of one byte. Is there any standard / algorithm for that?

Comment: what means  "store a chess move"?? what do you need to save in this byte?

Comment: https://lichess.org/blog/Wqa7GiAAAOIpBLoY/developer-update-275-improved-game-compression

Comment: @Berto99 as in memory, such that it has a one to one match with a unique move of a piece in a chess board, and can be retrieved later  so that I will know exactly what move has been played

Comment: You need to read about PGNs which are the most traditional way, and blog @DavidEisenstat has posted

Comment: If you enumerate all the possible combinations of from_square and to_square, you'll find somewhat less than 2048 of them: 11 bits.  If you pick what you think are the 127 most common ones, then you can use 8 bits for those (0xxxxxxx) and 12 bits for the rest.  I don't think there will be a way to get the average down to 1 byte without taking the board position into account.

Comment: If the move has context, then it's easy to encode a move in one byte. Out of context, there's no chance. Context means that the byte is part of a sequence of moves that describe the game from its beginning. So each byte describes a change in the game state. Out-of-context means that you can look at the bits and determine exactly which piece was moved, where it started, and where it ended. That takes two bytes.

Comment: Could you come back with some comments on the answers??

Comment: @trincot I am waiting for an answer with the least bits possible (not just byte) as I seen that reaching one byte is quite easy.

Comment: That is not what your question says. It says *"I want a standard move to take an average of one byte"*. So are you now moving the goal posts??

Comment: @trincot yes. can I? if not, I will ask another one.

Comment: It is just that you'll anyway need 8 bits for cases where there are 128 or more valid moves. So then you are asking for a variable length move-definition. Your question should be specific. I would suggest asking a new question, as there are already several answers here, based on your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chess Programming Wiki](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Encoding_Moves#MoveIndex) tells us:

> If the generated moves inside a move list are deterministic, one may encode moves as relative list index. Since the maximum number of moves per positions seems 218, one byte is enough to index the move. This encoding was used in early game databases.
>
> **Two Positions with 218 Moves each**
> [image]

So this requires that your implementation can generate all valid chess moves for a given position. The linked article mentions a few improvements to this method, but if your concern is only to stay in the 1-byte range, then this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Each player has a maximum of 16 pieces on the board.  You can identify the piece to move by defining the order (e. g. row-wise starting from a8) and then encoding the index of the piece in that order (0 to 15, so 4 bit).

Each piece then has a number of valid positions to move to.  The maximum number of valid target positions is found when a queen has no blocking pieces to the end of the board in all directions.

```
X • • • X • • •
• X • • X • • X
• • X • X • X •
• • • X X X • •
X X X X Q X X X
• • • X X X • •
• • X • X • X •
• X • • X • • X
```

If I counted right, that's 27 target squares.  You need 5 bit for that.  However, you can see that a pawn has a maximum of four different target squares, for which 2 bit are sufficient (except when it's on the seventh rank, when it can promote to four different pieces, so 12 targets, which need 4 bits).  A knight has up to 8, so 3 bit.  Bishop and rook: 4 bit.  King: up to 8 (castling is only possible if he is at the edge), 3 bit.

You can then define a move to use as many additional bits as indicated by the piece that is identified in the first part.  All you need to do is define the order in which the target moves (including possible promotions) are considered.

Comment: A pawn on the 7th rank can have 3 different moves x 4 possible promotions == 12 moves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the destination cell to eliminate most candidates, then enumerate the remaining ones in a predefined order, and finally select the correct one.

A small example to make it more clear. Let say you have a move from the left tower to position 34. Let say that, at the moment you do this move, you have 4 candidates that can reach this cell : pawn6, left tower, left knight, right knight. Your move can be encoded as following :
100010(binary for 34) 01(the left tower is the second possible choice).

Of course, if there are more than 4 choices, there will be more than 8 bits; but these cases are self flagged (you know if a position get more than 4 candidates) and are rare.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode a move within a 16 bit word as described by the [Chessprogramming website](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Encoding_Moves). Scroll down to Information Required / From-To Based and you will see a nice table with explanation of how to do it without losing any important information. Here is an image of the table (I couldn't copy/paste it on a nice format here):

[image]